# How to get element by ID in PDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

for example my View has an id

public static final String ID = "examplePlugin.views.SampleView"

How do I get an instance of this View (or any other thing in eclipse ) by id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For views you use methods on the current workbench page `IWorkbenchPage`. You can find the page with:

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
```

(this must be called from a plugin with the workbench running).

You can find an existing view with:

```
page.findView(id);
```

and create and show a view with:

```
page.showView(id);
```